# Best practice to structure service/factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was studying angularJs last week and there's something I'm not sure about.

For example, in a project that has some CRUDs of Student, Teacher and Supplier. Is it a good practice split the services/factory for each models (student, teacher and supplier)? or Is it better use one generic service/factory for the same models, like "write once, and run in everywhere"?. I think the second option maybe works for big projects, because you can write less code, but I have no idea about the maintenance.

**Obs:** The service/factory reffered above has functions with $http to list, add, edit and delete a registry from database.

And Is there any detailed style guide with best pratices for AngularJs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to angularJS I would advise you to check this angularjs style guide from Todd Motto, it's most likely best one online: 
https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Really has best practices using component based architecture. You will improve your code drastically and even merging to Angular would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you can manage the API endpoints at the back-end side you can create your services based on `$resource`. All you need (at the front-end side) is to set the endpoint URL. By call of `$resource` predefined methods like `get`, `save`, `delete` and etc. (you can add your custom methods as well) the `$resource` will submit HTTP requests with particular HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) to the defined API endpoint.